# goBack with useHistory react-router-dom firing old result api

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have two page (ListProduct and Basket).

[image: listproduct.png]

Link image (https://picshack.net/ib/XFZUHIhAaQ)

ListProduct contain product that I can add to cart, example i add item A with 1 quantity

And then I go to the basket (contain all product that I have added to cart). On position component Basket, I add more some product example I add more item A from 1 quantity to 3 quantity, fyi every add button it's updating data on my database so in database now the quantity of item A is 3.

and I .goBack() from view Basket to ListProduct with useHistory (react-router-dom).
on view ListProduct it's still 1 Quantity and my expecting result is 3. I don't know how this happen.

If i refresh page it's updated data item A to 3.
if i use .push('path-of-listproduct') from useHistory (react-router-dom) it's updated too (basket -> listproduct). I can't using this because .push() it's complicated to save or get path previous url.

Here my code:

ListProduct.jsx

```
export default function ListFive(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
    const [totQtyItem, setTotQtyItem] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const kategori = props.match.params.id;

        if (kategori === "promo") {
            let getPromoProducts = productAPI.newPromoProducts(5, 1);
    
            getPromoProducts.then((response) => {
                setProduct(response.data.data)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
        } else {
            let newProducts = productAPI.newProducts(10, 1);

            newProducts.then((response) => {
                setProduct(response.data.data)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
        }
    },[]);

    function FormRow(data) {
        return (
            <Kcard
                product={data}
                callBackAddItemTotal={callBackAddItemTotal}
                callBackDeleteItemTotal={callBackDeleteItemTotal}
            />
        );
    }

    const callBackAddItemTotal = (data) => {
        setTotQtyItem(data)
    }

    const callBackDeleteItemTotal = (data) => {
        setTotQtyItem(data)
    }

    return (
        <>              
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <Grid container spacing={1}>
                    <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={1}>
                        {
                            product.length >= 1 ?
                                product.map((promo, i) =>
                                    <FormRow 
                                        product={promo}
                                    />
                                )
                            :
                                <NotFoundPage 
                                    content="Produk Kosong"
                                />
                        }
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Kcard.jsx

```
export default function Kcard(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [carts, setCarts] = useState([]);
    const [qtyItem, setQtyItem] = useState(null);
    let data = { title: "Waiting for Data" };
    const [todo, setTodo] = useState(data);
    const [isData, setData] = useState(false);
    const [isFetching, setFetching] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {        
    // called after the first render
    async function fetchData() {
        let app_id = localStorage.getItem('sessionId');

        if (app_id === null) {
            localStorage.setItem('sessionId', lib.makeSessionId(40))
        } else {

            let getItemAct = cartAPI.getItems(app_id);
            getItemAct.then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                const adf = response.data.find(o => o.product_id === props.product.product._id);
                props.callBackAddItemTotal(response.data.length);
                if (adf !== undefined){
                    setQtyItem(adf.qty);
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
        }
    }
    fetchData();
},[]);

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                <GridList spacing={1} className={classes.gridList}>
                    <GridListTile key="fsd" cols={2} rows={2}>
                        {/* {console.log(qtyItem)} */}
                        <Link to={"/detail-product/" + props.product.product._id}>
                            <img
                                src="path-image"
                                className={
                                    props.product.product.stok <= 0 ?
                                        classes.imgFullHeightSoldOut
                                    :
                                        classes.imgFullHeight
                                }
                            />
                            {
                                props.product.product.stok <= 0 ?
                                    <div className={classes.soldOut}>Sold Out</div>
                                : 
                                    ""
                            }
                        </Link>

                        <div> **-** </div>

                        <div> **3** <div> 
                        
                        <div> **+** </div>
                    </GridListTile>
                </GridList>
            </Paper>
        </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
);
}
```

Thans for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As recommended in the react-router docs, history.location should not be used because it is mutable. You should get access to the **pathname** via a Route component or by using the withRouter HOC.

Link: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history/history-is-mutable

And saving the state of the cart directly to the database might present race conditions where the client/database fails to update and return the new value of the entry. It is better to handle the cart state using **Redux** or as **cookies** in the local storage, which is how most shops handle cart histories. If you want the cart data to persist, do the database update in the background.

Answer (score 0):

just share what I have done to resolve this

- ListProduct.jsx

> ```
> <FormRow 
>     product={promo}
>  />
> ```

change to

> ```
> <Kcard
>   product={data}
>   callBackAddItemTotal={callBackAddItemTotal}
>   callBackDeleteItemTotal={callBackDeleteItemTotal}
> />`
> ```